# add `shell.prefix()` in snakemake profile?

Tags: snakemake

For using `conda activate myenv` inside a script rule, I should add

```py
shell.prefix("source /usr/local/genome/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh;")
```

at the beginning of the Snakefile.

I would like to add this option in my profile. For example in `config.yaml` or in `sge-submit.py`.

I tried to add it in `sge-jobscript.sh`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a solution for this ? Do you have the same problem ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to add a prefix variable to your `config.yaml`:

```
prefix: "source /usr/local/genome/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh;"
```

and then in your snakefile:

```
shell.prefix(config["prefix"])
```